# How can I create a side canvas in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to create "InventoryView" which is a separate canvas to the map.

While BasicMap and InventoryView both inherit from AbstractGrid,
which itself inherits from Canvas, they are designed with different purposes.
The BasicMap is used to display the position of entities on the grid.
The InventoryView is used to display the items in the player's inventory and
allow the player to activate an item they click on.

The Final outcome should be like this:
[image]

I have managed to get this:

[image]

Now, I need to create the Inventory part.
I am trying with below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from constants import *

class AbstractGrid(tk.Canvas):
    
    def __init__(self, master, rows, cols, width, height, **kwargs):
        """

        master: The window in which the grid should be drawn. 
        rows: The integer number of rows in the grid.
        cols: The integer number of columns in the grid.
        width: The width of the grid canvas (in pixels). 
        height: The height of the grid canvas (in pixels). 
        **kwargs: Any other additional named parameters appropriate to tk.Canvas.
        """
        
        super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height, **kwargs)

        self._rows = rows
        self._cols = cols
        self._width = width
        self._height = height
        # calculate the grid width and height
        self._grid_w = width / cols
        self._grid_h = height / rows

class InventoryView(AbstractGrid):
    """
    InventoryView is a view class which inherits from AbstractGrid and displays the items the
    player has in their inventory.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, rows, **kwargs):
        """
        master: The window in which the grid should be drawn.
        row: The  number of rows in the game map
        """
        super().__init__(master, rows, cols=2, width=INVENTORY_WIDTH, height=height, **kwargs)
        master.title("Inventory")
    def draw(self,inventory):
        """
        Draws the inventory label and current items with their remaining lifetime
        """
    def toggle_item_activation(self, pixel, inventory):
        """
        Activates or deactivates the item (if one exists) in the row containing the pixel
        """
```

I know the functionaity depends on a lot of things but I am just trying to create the basic layout at this stage with all the titles and boundary as well.

Would anybody please help me to get the basic layout.

Thanks

Comment: Just create two frames in window and it will create a partition for you and you can do what you need

Comment: I think using `Text` or `Treeview` for the *"InventoryView"* is better than using `AbstractGrid`.

Comment: Ok Add text or whatever you want to add in another frame. the frames will just create a partition of your window

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root, relief="sunken")
Label(frame1, text="This text is in frame 1").pack()
frame1.pack(side="left")

frame2 = Frame(root)
Label(frame2, text="This text is in frame 1").pack()
frame2.pack(side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

Just create two frames in window and add widgets as you require. take help from above code.